# how to PARTLY share configurations between collections/cores in solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Configset(multicore)/collection.configureName(solrCloud) requires the whole porfolio of configs like spelling, stopwrods etc. other than schema and solrconfig, but in most cases, we simply need different schema and solrconfig for different collections/cores, all the other config files remain the same, so is it possiable to make different collections/cores share most of the conf files